# Workaround for Sharepoint 2013 Workflow 2013 suspended for duplicate profiles

Tags: sharepoint, duplicates, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-userprofile

We have duplicate profiles in our SharePoint 2013 system because we have one webapp that uses SAML authentication and a 2nd webapp to support BI function that uses Kerberos.  So most of our users have two profiles.  We are just now standing up Workflow Manager 2013 and found that it does not run when the submitter has two profiles in the system.  How do we workaround this limitation?